# How do I prevent a DataGridView from sharing rows?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I've made a custom DataGridViewCell that displays a custom control instead of the cell; but if the DataGridView uses shared rows, then the custom control instance is also shared, so you get strange behaviour (for example, hovering over buttons highlights all the buttons).  Also, I can't access the DataGridViewCell.Selected property, so I don't know what colour to paint the row.

How do I prevent a DataGridView from sharing rows?  I know I can add the rows using the Rows.Add(object[]) override, but then the first row is still shared (i.e. has index -1) so the problem with colours still applies.

I need to be able to tell the DataGridView not to share a row containing a custom cell.  Can that be done with attributes?  Can it be done at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set a Tooltip Text in one cell of the Row

A row cannot be shared in any of the following situations: 
 The row contains a single selected cell that is not in a selected column. 
 The row contains a cell with its ToolTipText or ContextMenuStrip properties set. 
 The row contains a DataGridViewComboBoxCell with its Items property set.

or read

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx

for more Information

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGridViewRowCollection.AddRange(params DataGridViewRow[] dataGridViewRows)
```

with

```
new[]{someDataGridviewRow}
```

worked for me.