# .Net DataGridView difference between Rows.Add and Rows.AddRange with custom DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow

Curious behaviour of the `DataGridViewControl` cost me quite some time today.

**TL;DR**: `Rows.Add(MyOwnFancyRow)` adds a clone of `MyOwnFancyRow` to the DGV whereas `Rows.AddRange(new MWERow[]{MyOwnFancyRow})` adds `MyOwnFancyRow` itself. Figured that out after writing all of it, but still do not understand *why*.

**Hypothesis:** `DataGridView.Rows.Add()` and `DataGridView.Rows.AddRange()` handle the insertion of new rows based on a `RowTemplate` differently.

**Experiment:** I work with *unbound* `DataGridView`s, designed to display complex classes and give the user ways to configure instances of this classes to their taste. I may load some instances from XML and display them, as well as giving the user the opportunity to add new instances (think `dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = true;`)

To handle the proper displaying of these instances I create custom `DataGridViewRow`s to handle all the interaction between user and instance. This way I can plug my instance into another `DataGridView` on a totally different form without having to copy all the handling code. The row does it all for me.

Please consider this not overly complex class for my minimal (non) working example:

```
class MWEObject : ICloneable {
    public string Value1 { get; internal set; }
    public double Value2 { get; internal set; }

    public delegate void OnMWEObjectChanged();
    public event OnMWEObjectChanged ObjectChanged;

    public MWEObject() {
        Value1 = "Default"; Value2 = 0;
    }

    public MWEObject(string in_Value1, double in_Value2) {
        Value1 = in_Value1; Value2 = in_Value2;
    }

    public void UpdateObject(MWEObject in_Object) {
        Value1 = in_Object.Value1;
        Value2 = in_Object.Value2;
        if (ObjectChanged != null)
            ObjectChanged.Invoke();
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return "Value1: " + Value1 + " Value2: " + Value2.ToString("0.000");
    }

    public object Clone() {
        return new MWEObject(Value1, Value2);
    }
}
```

This class on its own cannot comfortably go into a `DataGridView`, so here is the custom `DataGridViewRow` to handle the displaying and updating (I tried to keep it as complete but brief as possible, so the concept gets clear and I can get pointed to errors):

```
class MWERow : DataGridViewRow {
    public MWEObject theObject { get; private set; }
    DataGridView templateDGV;
    bool changing;
    public MWERow(DataGridView in_template) {
        templateDGV = in_template;
        theObject = new MWEObject();
        changing = false;
        CreateCells(templateDGV);
    }

    public MWERow(MWEObject in_Object, DataGridView in_template): this(in_template) {
        theObject = in_Object;
        theObject.ObjectChanged += TheObject_ObjectChanged;
    }

    private void TheObject_ObjectChanged() {
        if (!changing)
            SetupValues();
    }

    private void RowAdded() {
        SetupValues();
    }

    private void CellChanged(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        if (DataGridView != null && !changing)
            theObject.UpdateObject(
                new MWEObject(
                    e.ColumnIndex == Cells["Value1"].ColumnIndex ? (string)Cells["Value1"].Value : theObject.Value1,
                    e.ColumnIndex == Cells["Value2"].ColumnIndex ? (double)Cells["Value2"].Value : theObject.Value2));
    }

    private void SetupValues() {
        if (DataGridView != null && Cells["Value1"].RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            changing = true;
            Cells["Value1"].Value = theObject.Value1;
            Cells["Value2"].Value = theObject.Value2;
            changing = false;
        }
    }

    public override object Clone() {
        return new MWERow(/*(MWEObject)theObject.Clone(),*/templateDGV);
    }
// Clever telling the DataGridView what to do starts here
    public static void SetupDGV(DataGridView theDGV) {
        bool oldState = theDGV.AllowUserToAddRows;
        theDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        theDGV.Rows.Clear();
        theDGV.Columns.Clear();

        theDGV.RowsAdded -= TheDGV_RowsAdded;
        theDGV.RowsAdded += TheDGV_RowsAdded;
        theDGV.CellEndEdit -= TheDGV_CellEndEdit;
        theDGV.CellEndEdit += TheDGV_CellEndEdit;
        theDGV.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged -= TheDGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
        theDGV.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += TheDGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;

        theDGV.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "Value1", HeaderText = "Value 1", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() { ValueType = typeof(string) } });
        theDGV.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "Value2", HeaderText = "Value 2", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() { ValueType = typeof(double) } });

        theDGV.RowTemplate = new MWERow(theDGV);

        theDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = oldState;
    }

    private static void TheDGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (((DataGridView)sender).IsCurrentCellDirty)
            ((DataGridView)sender).CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

    private static void TheDGV_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        if (((DataGridView)sender).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn))
            ((MWERow)(((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex])).CellChanged(e);
    }

    private static void TheDGV_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dgv != null)
        {
            int StartIndex = e.RowIndex;
            if ((dgv.AllowUserToAddRows && StartIndex != 0) && StartIndex == dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
                StartIndex--;
            foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(StartIndex, e.RowCount))
                ((MWERow)dgv.Rows[i]).RowAdded();
            if (dgv.AllowUserToAddRows && e.RowIndex == dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
                ((MWERow)dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1]).RowAdded();
        }
    }
}
```

The concept behind this row is the following:

- A static method allows me to set up any `DataGridView` I want
- The `DataGridView` gets assigned specific event handlers to handle things as adding rows and editing cells => this keeps the code of my form clean and I have a way to display the correct values after adding the row
- Columns are added to the `DataGridView`
- The `CellTemplate` gets set to the most basic row => The one where the object withing gets instantiated with default values (Shows values in the "Add new Row"-Row, defaults are always nice)
- Note the Clone method (which has to be there according to the documentation). We will move the comment around a bit in a short while.

The Row itself starts off by creating the cells it requires (`CreateCells(templateDGV);`), which is the reason I have to provide a link to the DataGridView this row is going to be added to => I need the column names.

To top everything off we need a form with 1 `DataGridView` called dgv and 6 `Button`s, so here it is:

```
public partial class frm_Test : Form {
    List<MWEObject> theObjects;
    List<MWEObject> theSecondObjects;
    public frm_Test() {
        InitializeComponent();
        theObjects = new List<MWEObject>()
        {
            new MWEObject("test 1", 1),
            new MWEObject("test 2", 2),
            new MWEObject("test 3", 3),
            new MWEObject("test 4", 4)
        };
        theSecondObjects = new List<MWEObject>();
    }

    private void btn_SetupDGV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MWERow.SetupDGV(dgv);
        dgv.RowsAdded += Dgv_RowsAdded;
    }

    private void Dgv_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dgv != null)
        {
            int StartIndex = e.RowIndex;
            if ((dgv.AllowUserToAddRows && StartIndex != 0) && StartIndex == dgv.Rows.Count - 1)
                StartIndex--;
            foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(StartIndex, e.RowCount))
                theSecondObjects.Add(((MWERow)dgv.Rows[i]).theObject);
        }
    }

    private void btn_ShowLists_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Rows: " + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dgv.Rows.Cast<MWERow>().Select(x => x.theObject.ToString() + (x.IsNewRow ? " isNew" : ""))));
        MessageBox.Show("List: " + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, theObjects.Select(x => x.ToString())));
        MessageBox.Show("Second List: " + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, theSecondObjects.Select(x => x.ToString())));
    }

    private void btn_AddSingleItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        dgv.Rows.Add(new MWERow(new MWEObject("1 Test", 1), dgv));
        dgv.Rows.Add(new MWERow(new MWEObject("2 Test", 2), dgv));
        dgv.Rows.Add(new MWERow(new MWEObject("3 Test", 3), dgv));
        dgv.Rows.Add(new MWERow(new MWEObject("4 Test", 4), dgv));
        dgv.Rows.Add(new MWERow(new MWEObject("5 Test", 5), dgv));
    }

    private void btn_AddBulkItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        dgv.Rows.AddRange(new MWERow[]
            {
                new MWERow(new MWEObject("1 Test", 1), dgv),
                new MWERow(new MWEObject("2 Test", 2), dgv),
                new MWERow(new MWEObject("3 Test", 3), dgv),
                new MWERow(new MWEObject("4 Test", 4), dgv),
                new MWERow(new MWEObject("5 Test", 5), dgv)
            });
    }

    private void btn_AddSingleList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        foreach (MWEObject o in theObjects)
            dgv.Rows.Add(new MWERow(o, dgv));
    }

    private void btn_AddBulkList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        dgv.Rows.AddRange(theObjects.Select(x => new MWERow(x, dgv)).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Short description of what the buttons do:

- One button sets the DataGridView up
- One button displays: the "theObject"s from all rows, the content of the "theObjects"-List (fixed) and the content of the "theSecondObjects"-List (growing with each add)
- One button Adds new row instances to the DGV one-by-one (Rows.Add()) "Single Add"
- One button Adds new row instances to the DGV by bulk (Rows.AddRange()) "Bulk Add"
- One button Adds new rows based on the "theObjects"-List one-by-one (Rows.Add()) "Single Add List"
- One button Adds new rows based on the "theObjects"-List by bulk (Rows.AddRange()) "Bulk Add List"

**Observations:** We will vary the Clone() method step by step. We start with the simpelest clone: `return new MWERow(templateDGV);`

- Single Add: All entries in the DGV show the default values and their "theObject"s are on Default values
- Bulk Add: All entries in the DGV show the values they are supposed to show and the "theObject"s have the correct values
- Single Add List: Same behaviour as "Single Add"
- Bulk Add List: Same behaviour as "Bulk Add"
- Editing each 2nd entry of each block shows that:

  - All Rows are properly connected to the objects they contain (Display 1 (from row) and 3 (List where everything gets added) match
  - Only the rows added through "AddRange()" keep the connection to the objects they originate from (this can only be tested for those items in the "theObjects"-List because their instances exist out of the adding scope).
  - Adding the objects from the "theObjects"-List twice (by bulk!) shows that changing one element (say the third) changes every row that links to this element => The row is working in principle

Moving on to cloning the half-cooked way: `return new MWERow((MWEObject)theObject, templateDGV);`

- No matter how the adding is done, all rows show the values they are supposed to show and contain the values they are supposed to contain
- Editing one entry changes all other entries based on the same object, regardless of the exact way how it is added
- When adding a new row by using the "Add new row here"-Row, the values in that row start defaulting to whichever row is last in the already added collection

The last step, going for a full clone: `return new MWERow((MWEObject)theObject.Clone(), templateDGV);`

- No matter how the adding is done, all rows show what they are supposed to show
- Only those rows that are added by bulk retain a connection to the same object in the background and reflect its changes correctly
- When adding a new row, every new "new row" has the default values as it should have

These observations are consistent, regardless of `AllowUserToAddRows = true/false;` and subscribing to `dgv.RowsAdded` in the form or not. (There might still be an issue with my index handling of the rowAdded-Event though)

**Conclusion:**

Short: WTF?

Long: There seems to be something wrong with how new rows are created. The way I understand the documentation, the general procedure is the following:

- An instance of a row is given as `RowTemplate`. I set this template to show the default values
- For the "new Row"-Row a clone of this template is created.
- Upon editing this "new Row", it moves into the realm of edited rows, my value moving trickery can take place so that the object inside the row can reflect the newly edited values
- Since this clone of a new row is now a fully functional row, we need a new "new Row", so we clone the template to have a fresh start.

When adding rows programatically the template row should not be of any consequence, since we are providing a fully grown row, complete with a non-default object. The only way I can explain the observed behaviour is this:

- Using `Rows.Add()` takes the row and inserts a clone of it into the DGV
- Using `Rows.AddRange()` inserts the row itself

Because I just thought of that so clearly I tested it with a property assigned to the row that gets not copied in the clone method (Or which gets set to "Cloned" inside the clone method). When using the `Add()`-Method the property's value is gone, when using `AddRange()` it is there. The rest of the behaviour is in line with what I wrote above and makes sense when the whole process of cloning is indeed involved.

**Question**: Why does `Rows.AddRange()` behave differently to `Rows.Add()`? What have I missed? Why is there no detailed guide to writing ones own `DataGridViewRow` around? Is this by design?

Sorry for this long post but I wanted to make my problem clear and show all I have tested... And I seem to have figured out *what* is happening, I am just left to wonder about the *why*...

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot to digest.  Maybe look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewRowCollection.cs,3b3d29d66f42852c)

Comment: My demo class is simple. Add a property of type enum and see that the DataSource does not readily produce a ComboBoxColumn. Let alone a property of a certain custom type which shal be fed through a List and be also accessed through a ComboBoxColumn. I do not try to apply business logic to the UI grid, but UI logic to an object by means of an intermediate UI-Object, the DataGridViewRow. Think of displaying an imagecolumn to give en error indication which will only be needed if the application does run with an UI. My business object should not care about giving infos to users, the UI should.

Comment: If I need an intermediate Object I can bind the datasource to anyway, then I can use a custom row directly. The main reason I NEED this row is: There is UI stuff happening that has no place in my business object. I have additional outputs like the aforementionend visual hint that something is different, I need to select a property of type `Class A` from a specific `List<Class A>` via a combo box, I need to select enum values via a combobox. From what I have seen now that I fiddled with DataSources a bit, that, too, involves more effort than just `dgv.DataSource = BindingList<MyFancyClass>;`

Comment: @LarsTech: Thank you for the link, very interesting but unfortunately I don't see much difference between both calls. it might have something to do with shared/unshared rows, a concept I don't fully understand up to now, maybe someone can enlighten me. I found this answer which confirms what I have found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1820040/1968308 , I'm only wondering about the WHY now.

Comment: Someone has deleted their comments over the weekend, so 2/3 of my comments seem now strangely out of context...